# "Sub-parsers" in pipes-attoparsec

Tags: parsing, haskell, attoparsec, haskell-pipes

I'm trying to parse binary data using pipes-attoparsec in Haskell. The reason pipes (proxies) are involved is to interleave reading with parsing to avoid high memory use for large files. Many binary formats are based on blocks (or chunks), and their sizes are often described by a field in the file. I'm not sure what a parser for such a block is called, but that's what i mean by "sub-parser" in the title. The problem I have is to implement them in a concise way without a potentially large memory footprint. I've come up with two alternatives that each fail in some regard.

Alternative 1 is to read the block into a separate bytestring and start a separate parser for it. While concise, a large block will cause high memory use.

Alternative 2 is to keep parsing in the same context and track the number of bytes consumed. This tracking is error-prone and seems to infest all the parsers that compose into the final blockParser. For a malformed input file it could also waste time by parsing further than indicated by the size field before the tracked size can be compared.

```
import Control.Proxy.Attoparsec
import Control.Proxy.Trans.Either
import Data.Attoparsec as P
import Data.Attoparsec.Binary
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS

parser = do
    size <- fromIntegral <$> anyWord32le

    -- alternative 1 (ignore the Either for simplicity):
    Right result <- parseOnly blockParser <$> P.take size
    return result

    -- alternative 2
    (result, trackedSize) <- blockparser
    when (size /= trackedSize) $ fail "size mismatch"
    return result

blockParser = undefined

main = withBinaryFile "bin" ReadMode go where
    go h = fmap print . runProxy . runEitherK $ session h
    session h = printD <-< parserD parser <-< throwParsingErrors <-< parserInputD <-< readChunk h 128
    readChunk h n () = runIdentityP go where
        go = do
            c <- lift $ BS.hGet h n
            unless (BS.null c) $ respond c *> go
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to call this a "fixed-input" parser.

I can tell you how `pipes-parse` will do it.  You can see a preview of what I'm about to describe in `pipes-parse` in the [`parseN`](https://github.com/Gabriel439/Haskell-Pipes-Parse-Library/blob/master/Control/Proxy/Parse/Commit.hs#L328) and [`parseWhile`](https://github.com/Gabriel439/Haskell-Pipes-Parse-Library/blob/master/Control/Proxy/Parse/Commit.hs#L365) functions of the library.  Those are actually for generic inputs, but I wrote similar ones for example `String` parsers as well [here](https://github.com/Gabriel439/Haskell-Pipes-Parse-Library/blob/master/Control/Proxy/String/Backtrack.hs#L263) and [here](https://github.com/Gabriel439/Haskell-Pipes-Parse-Library/blob/master/Control/Proxy/String/Backtrack.hs#L309).

The trick is really simple, you insert a fake end of input marker where you want the parser to stop, run the parser (which will fail if it hits the fake end of input marker), then remove the end of input marker.

Obviously, that's not as easy as I make it sound, but it's the general principle.  The tricky parts are:

- Doing it in such a way that it still streams.  The one I linked doesn't do that, yet, but the way you do this in a streaming way is to insert a pipe upstream that counts bytes flowing through it and then inserts the end-of-input marker at the correct spot.
- Not interfering with existing end of input markers

This trick can be adapted for `pipes-attoparsec`, but I think the best solution would be for `attoparsec` to directly include this feature.  However, if that solution is not available, then we can restrict the input that is fed to the `attoparsec` parser.

Comment: Inserting a pipe that counts upstream sounds interesting, but how will it know how many bytes to count? This value is only discovered by the parser downstream, which can't call request directly with the value as parameter, as it is run by parserD.

Comment: @absence Well, ignore the pipes-attoparsec interface for now because Renzo and I will fix it soon.  The fixed input parser internally uses a pipe that restricts the byte count.  Think of it like: `parser1 >> (restrict n >-> parser2) >> parser3`.  The fixed width combinatorial inserts something like `restrict` upstream of that given parser.  It is more complicated than that, but pretty similar in spirit.

Comment: The links are dead

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I finally figured out how to do this and I've codified this pattern in the `pipes-parse` library.  The [`pipes-parse` tutorial](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pipes-parse/1.0.0/doc/html/Control-Proxy-Parse-Tutorial.html) explains how to do this, specifically in the "Nesting" section.

The tutorial only explains this for datatype-agnostic parsing (i.e. a generic stream of elements), but you can extend it to work with `ByteString`s to work, too.

The two key tricks that make this work are:

- Fixing `StateP` to be global (in `pipes-3.3.0`)
- Embedding the sub-parser in a transient `StateP` layer so that it uses a fresh leftovers context

The `pipes-attoparsec` is going to release an update soon that builds on `pipes-parse` so that you can use these tricks in your own code.

Comment: Can i call passUpTo inside a Data.Attoparsec.Parser like the parser function in my example? Or is it better to combine multiple small parseD proxies instead of using one huge Parser that, while composed from smaller Parsers, is a black box to pipes-attoparsec?

Comment: You want `parseD` to loop over small `Parser`s because it cannot free memory until each `Parser` completes.  `attoparsec` never frees input until the `Parser` completes because it always reserves the right to backtrack within a `Parser`.  The only way to parse something in constant memory is identify boundaries in the stream where it is safe to flush previous input.  For example, if you are parsing a huge CSV file, then you might define a `Parser` for each line of the CSV file called `parseLine`, and then just run `parseD` to generate a stream of parsed lines.

Comment: @absence@ Also, `pipes-bytestring` is going to provide a `passBytesUpTo` primitive that will allow you to delimit an entire `attoparsec` parser to a fixed input while still streaming in constant memory.  That's probably closer to what you want.  The idea is that you put `passBytesUpTo` *upstream* of a call to `Control.Proxy.Attoparsec.parse` and it will run that parser in a fixed number of bytes.